# SQL Reporting Services: 2008 R2, web app showing unauthorized access

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have an issue with my SSRS 2008 R2. When I am trying to access my web app (externally i.e. https://webapp.com) then use the SSRS to generate the report my web app is not passing credentials correctly to the SSRS so I am getting 401: Unauthorised.

However, when I connect to the web app through the actual server and use same url just internally everything is working fine even with RSWindowsNegotiate and no Anonymous authentication. So Kerberos and SPNs are fine cuz everything works fine but only internally.

Then I performed some investigation and it seems that externally I am not able to do double authentication or IE is not passing credentials to the SSRS. What my web app is doing:

1. I open the app, I need to input the user name and password if user is part of the AD (kerberos authentication and SPNs)
2. Click on the generate report and here app should also pass the credentials and if user is already saved in the session i should check that user against AD (kerberos and SPN).

I have checked authentication and:

1. When the authentication set to RSWindowsNegotiate the external access via web app does not work. Kerberos and SPNs are set correctly.
2. When I set anonymous authentication to Anonymous the external access via web app is working fine
3. I have tried to use Unattended Execution Account but it didnt work as well

However, I would not like to leave Anonymous authentication on my production environment so having some additional security would be great.

Do you have any ideas why is it happening?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this when SSRS2008R2 was new and shiny. At the time I did get to the bottom of it but I've long forgotten why it happens. The long and the short of it is (as you say) no double auth.

For public facing web access the usual way to sort this out is to wrap the report in a report control in an asp.net page. The report control authenticates on the user's behalf. The origin of the credentials it uses is up to the author of the app hosting it. Yes, I know - this is a sucky arrangement. Blergh.

You could also write your own security provider for SSRS. This is a Herculean undertaking of the sort rarely approved by pointy haired bosses who prefer to keep asking why you aren't finished. If you do happen to complete the Twelve Tasks and return from the underworld I believe you get a princess and half a kingdom to go with your reports.

Comment: Thanks. However adding new report control in asp.net page would not work as it would need to go through full dev cycle. I have read about mimicking anonymous authentication by setting different user to run "app pool" of SSRS. It was easy to set under SQL 2005 when the actual SSRS app was under IIS but with 2008 the SSRS has its own http specific app pool. :(